# How do you set up permanent caching for cloudfront?

Tags: http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I've read through the documentation and attempted to setup permanent cloudfront caching. The idea is that once you download an image you shouldn't need to download it again. I'm looking at my network tab and I don't think it is. Can someone tell me if this file has the correct cache settings?

https://d2t4fc8ff77neh.cloudfront.net/cardSrcMedia/1abqkohet_plain_red_heart_graphic_with_a_drop_shadow_0071-0910-0216-0922_SMU.jpg

My headers:

```
var headers = {
  'Content-Length': options.data.length,
  'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
  'Expires': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 5,
  'x-amz-acl': 'public-read',
  'Content-Type': options.type
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your image is being cached by CloudFront, but your expires header value isn't valid.

From the HTTP 1.1 spec (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

> The format is an absolute date and time as defined by HTTP-date in
>   section 3.3.1; it MUST be in RFC 1123 date format

and

> HTTP/1.1 clients and caches MUST treat other invalid date formats,
>   especially including the value "0", as in the past (i.e., "already
>   expired").

and

> To mark a response as "never expires," an origin server sends an
>   Expires date approximately one year from the time the response is
>   sent. HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD NOT send Expires dates more than one
>   year in the future.

It's probably better to use a Cache-control header as this supersedes the Expires header. Something like this should produce the same effect:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
```

Comment: The [CloudFront docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html) also support the position of using `Cache-Control` instead of `Expires`.  Also, the question really seems to be more about browser caching, but note that CloudFront does not guarantee that it will cache the objects for the time specified, only that it won't cache them *longer*... covered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26638663/1695906) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32878535/1695906).